# Is there a way to find our that ~ in Symfony config means?

Tags: symfony, yaml

I know that the `~` value in the Symfony config files means `null` or `default`:

```
framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: ~
```

But is there a way find out what this default value actually is? For example the `strict_requirements` property is set to `%kernel.debug%` in a project created with Symfony 2.8. The skeleton of the a new Symfony 3.4 project defines it as `~`.

It would be helpful (as example) to know if `~` defaults to `%kernel.debug%`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a command line which displays the default configuration values:

```
php bin/console config:dump-reference framework
```

And another one to display the actual configuration:

```
php bin/console debug:config framework
```